# Trouble compiling LaTex in Textmate

Tags: textmate

I am trying to compile latex code in text mate 2.0 on OS X 10.9.5, but every time I hit Command-R it gives me this error:

**"Failure Running Typeset & View (PDF); Command returned error status code 1."**.

I have tried reverting back to defaults by deleting all of Textmate's files as well as reinstalling Bundle-Support as suggested in this post https://github.com/textmate/markdown.tmbundle/issues/19 but it just doesn't work for me.

I have tried reinstalling MacTex and Textmate and changing my PATH Variable. Currently my PATH Variable, which I'm sure is wrong, is $PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin.

Also I'm not sure if it is much help but this is the file for the Typeset & View (PDF) Command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby18
# coding: utf-8

require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/process"
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/htmloutput"
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/save_current_document"

# To enable the typesetting of unsaved documents, you must change the “Save” setting of
# this command to “Current File” and add the variable TM_LATEX_AUTOSAVE to TextMate's
# Shell Variables preferences. Be warned that your document must be encoded as UTF-8 if
# you exercise this option — becauseTextMate.save_current_document cannot know the file 
# encoding you prefer.

TextMate.save_current_document unless ENV["TM_LATEX_AUTOSAVE"].nil?

texmate = ENV["TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT"] + "/bin/texmate.py"
engine_version = TextMate::Process.run(texmate, "version")
TextMate::HTMLOutput.show(:title => "Typesetting “#{ENV["TM_DISPLAYNAME"] || File.basename(ENV["TM_FILEPATH"])}”…", :sub_title => engine_version) do |io|
   TextMate::Process.run(texmate, 'latex', :interactive_input => false) do |line|
   io << line
   end
end
::Process.exit($?.exitstatus || 0) # exitstatus is nil if our process is prematurely terminated (SIGINT)
```

Here is the document I am trying to compile:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
    Please work.
\end{document}
```

Is there any solution to this problem? If not, what are some other alternatives for writing my Problem Sets in Latex? I would like to use TextMate because of its macro feature but I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Could you please add a (minimal) example document that leads to the error you described?

Comment: Okay I added the document I am trying to compile that leads to the error.

Comment: Can you compile at the command line? If not, what output do you get? Your PATH does not seem to include the path to your TeX binaries, if you installed with MacTeX. Can you compile with `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/<architecture>/pdflatex <filename>`? `architecture` would be something relevant to Mac OS X, I'm not sure what exactly.